# list of values from other rows into one row

Tags: mysql, list, subquery

I have Mytable:

```
key  userID    colour

1     1         blue
2     1         red
3     2         green
```

I am trying to get this:

select distinct userid, (select colour from Mytable ?) as list_of_colours

ie

```
  userID    list_of_colours

  1         blue,red
  2         green
```

Q1 Is using a subquery the way to go here?
Q2 What should the subquery be please?

Thank you very much.

Nick

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select userID , group_concat(color) from Mytable group by userID;
```

It will give the results as you required.